# Big theta notation and Quadratic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, quadratics

In the book Introduction to Algorithms (the renowned CLRS), the author writes in the 3rd Chapter, Growth of functions :

"Consider any quadratic function: $f\left(n\right)=an^2+bn+c$, where a, b and c are constants and $a>0$. Throwing away the lower-order terms and ignoring the constant yields: $f(n)=\Theta(n^2)$. Formally we take the constants $c_1=a/4$, $c_2=7a/4$ and $n_0=2\cdot\max\left(\frac{\left|b\right|}{a},\sqrt{\frac{\left|c\right|}{a}}\right)$. You may verify that $0\le c_1n^2\le an^2+bn+c\le c_2n^2$ for all $n\ge n_0$."

I'm having difficulty in discovering the term: $n_0=2\cdot\max\left(\frac{\left|b\right|}{a},\sqrt{\frac{\left|c\right|}{a}}\right)$.

I tried to calculate $f\left(n\right)$ for $ n = \frac{\left|b\right|}{a}$ and got:
$$f(n)= c,b<0$$
$$f(n)=\frac{2b^2}{a}+c, b>0$$
and for $n=\sqrt{\frac{\left|c\right|}{a}}$ and got:
$$f\left(n\right)=b\sqrt{\frac{\left|c\right|}{a}}, c<0$$
$$f\left(n\right)=2c+b\sqrt{\frac{\left|c\right|}{a}}, c>0$$
Nevertheless, I have not got any clue as to how these constants were obtained and how can I derive its significance.

Comment: It would be much easier to just take $c_1=a, c_2=a+b+c$ and $n_0=1$... It seems like your book is making it hard on purpose :D

Comment: I think they are trying to generalize the result, may be.